# Equivalent to Basic's Module

Tags: java, android

My Android app contains some functions that used by few activities.
At this moment this looks like:

```
MainActivity extends Activity {
 ...
 public static int someFunction(int arg1) {
  return arg1 * arg1;
 }
}
```

From other activity, it calls `MainActivity.someFunction(arg1)`. Works correct but looks ugly. I think that Basic's construction "Module" (all members are static, only static constructor available and by default, members call without a name of the module) is better for it because allows dividing app-logics on "view" and "engine". As I know Java doesn't have a construction like this:

```
module FN {
 public int someFunction(int arg1) {
  return arg1 * arg1;
 }
}
```

Please suggest me something like if it exists.

Comment: I suppose you refer to a VB Module (which is, basically, a container of methods and/or variables) equivalent. Try with `Class`.

Comment: the question is about java so this is not an answer but you could also use Kotlin that allows you to define methods in Kotlin files without having to define a class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something that resembles a Toolbox.

```
public class Toolbox {

    public int myFunction(int arg1) {
        return arg1 * arg1;
    }

}
```

And then implement it in your class:

```
public class MyClass {

    private Toolbox t = new Toolbox();

    public void doSomething(int arg1, int arg2) {
        int val = t.myFunction(arg1) + t.myFunction(arg2);
    }

}
```

Ofcource you could make the method static, but then you would have to call `Toolbox.myFunction`. Which is probably to verbose, compared to a basic module.

Answer (score 2):

You could use static imports to get a similar usage as with Basics modules. As specified here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html

> The static import construct allows unqualified access to static members without inheriting from the type containing the static members. Instead, the program imports the members, either individually:
>
> `import static java.lang.Math.PI;`
>
> or en masse:
>
> `import static java.lang.Math.*;`
>
> Once the static members have been imported, they may be used without qualification:
>
> `double r = cos(PI * theta);`